# Can a probability CDF be discontinuous?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I was given the following stochastic process:
$ X(t) = V h(t-Z)$ , $t > 0$

Where $f_V (v) = 1/2, 0\leq v\leq 2$ , $f_Z(z) = 2 e^{-2z}, z\geq 0$ , and:

$
  h(t) = \begin{cases} 
          1,  & 0 \leq t\leq 1 \\
          0, & \text{otherwise}
       \end{cases}
    \
$

I was asked to find the CDF of $X(1/2)$. What I did is to write:

$ F_{X(1/2)} (k)= P({X(1/2)}\leq k) = P(0 \leq z \leq 1/2)P(V \leq k) + P(Z > 1/2)P(k \geq 0)$

Solving this I get:

$
  F_{X(1/2)} (k) = \begin{cases} 
          1,  & k \geq 2 \\
          (1-e^{-1})\frac{k}{2} + e^{-1}, & 0 \leq k \leq 2 \\
          0 & k < 0 
       \end{cases}
    \
$

I'm not sure about this result because this function is discontinuous at $k=0$. If I wanted to get, for example, the PDF by derivation I would get: $f_{X(1/2)}(k)=(1-e^{-1})/2$ which has an area $1-e^{-1} \neq 1$.

Is something wrong with my reasoning ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have a discontinuous CDF.  In fact, every discrete distribution has a discontinuous CDF; however, your question relates to a mixed distribution with a combination of density and discrete probability mass.  Consider the example

$$W \mid X = \min(X, 2), \\ X \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\lambda = 1).$$  Then $W$ is what we call a right-censored exponential random variable:  $W = X$ if $X < 2$, otherwise $W = 2$.  Hence $$\Pr[W \le w] = \begin{cases} 0, & w < 0 \\ 1 - e^{-w}, & 0 \le w < 2 \\ 1, & w \ge 2. \end{cases}$$  There is a nonzero density for $W$ in the interval $(0,2)$, and then a discrete probability mass at $W = 2$ with value $\Pr[W = 2] = \Pr[X > 2] = e^{-2}$.

That said, we need to take a closer look at your computations.  I will use the indicator function $\mathbb 1$ in place of your $h(t)$.

I get $$\begin{align}
X(1/2) &= V \mathbb 1 (0 \le 1/2 - Z \le 1) \\
&= \begin{cases}V, & |Z| \le 1/2 \\ 0, & |Z| > 1/2 \end{cases} \\
&= \begin{cases} V, & 0 \le Z \le 1/2 \\ 0, & Z > 1/2. \end{cases}
\end{align}$$
This piecewise definition is the origin of the discontinuous nature of the CDF.  Proceeding with our computations,
$$\begin{align}
F_{X(1/2)}(x) &= \Pr[X(1/2) \le x] \\
&= \Pr[V \le x \mid 0 \le Z \le 1/2] \Pr[0 \le Z \le 1/2] + \Pr[0 \le x \mid Z > 1/2] \Pr[Z > 1/2] \\
&= \left( \frac{x}{2} \mathbb 1 (0 \le x \le 2) + \mathbb 1 (x > 2) \right) (1 - e^{-1}) + \mathbb 1(x \ge 0) e^{-1} \\
&= \begin{cases} 0, & x < 0 \\ \frac{x}{2} (1 - e^{-1}) + e^{-1} , & 0 \le x \le 2 \\ 1, & x > 2.\end{cases}
\end{align}$$
This is equivalent to your solution.  While it is true that the density equals $$f_{X(1/2)}(x) = \frac{1 - e^{-1}}{2}$$ for $0 < x < 2$, there is also a discrete probability mass at $x = 0$:  $$\Pr[X = 0] = e^{-1},$$ which we can see by going back to the original definitions:  $$\Pr[X(1/2) = 0] = \Pr[|Z| > 1/2] = \Pr[Z > 1/2] = e^{-2/2} = e^{-1}.$$

Comment: Great explanation. This mix of continuous and discrete random variables was very confusing to me.